# Passing the data stored in Json format from excel sheet to UI of application using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, json, selenium

1.I have an excel sheet that has Two columns one is Usecase, and second is Parameters.

2.In Usecase column cell Login data is given.

3.In Parameters cell the following values are given in Json format Application URL;element xpath;element Username; Password xpath and Password is given.

```
{https://ui.freecrm.com/, "usernamexpath":"//input[@id = 'UserName']", "username":"admin", "password xpath" = ''//input[@id = 'Password']", "password": "Pass_123", "loginButton":"//input[@value = 'Log in']"}
```

4.Now I need to read the excel sheet cell values using Selenium Webdriver, and then Login the application by fetching the data from Parameter cell one by one.
I am not able to find any solution till yet please support if anyone has idea.
here is code which i have written:

```
                  import java.io.FileReader;
                  import java.io.IOException;
                  import java.io.Reader;
                  import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
                  import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
                  import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
                  import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
                  import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;


                  public class JSONDataExample {
                  String n;

                  public String readJSONData(String keyword) throws IOException, ParseException{

                  Reader reader = new FileReader("./data/testdata.xlsx");

                  JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

                  JSONArray jsonArr = (JSONArray)parser.parse(reader);

                  for(Object obj : jsonArr){

                  JSONObject jo = (JSONObject)obj; 
                  n = (String)jo.get(keyword);

                 }

       return n;

        }

                  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException{
                  JSONDataExample e = new JSONDataExample();
                  String a = e.readJSONData("URL");
                  System.out.println(a);
                  String b = e.readJSONData("usernamexpath");
                  String c = e.readJSONData("username");
                  String d = e.readJSONData("password xpath");
                  String e = e.readJSONData("password");
                  String f = e.readJSONData("loginButton");
                 }

         }
```

Comment: please post what you tried

Comment: Below Code I have written, But it is not working:

Comment: @DanielM I have added the code